# ActionBar coloring lost on nested preference screens (android)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, theming

I am trying to make an app that allows for accent color theming throughout the app so the user can pick whatever color they would like. Because this is after the app starts up, it cannot be changed via XML android styling and must instead be done programatically with java.

I managed to set the colors based on the theme selected (more or less, still working out kinks) but I noticed that in nested Preference Screens the actionbar defaults to the XML style of gray. How would I change the actionbar of all nested Preference Screens?

here is a video demonstrating the theming functionality and you can see on the second preference screen the actionbar loses the color and turns gray.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eStx4Hc8fsQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of fixing this and there really didn't seem a way to handle it without a lot of hacky hacky stuff. Eventually I ran into issues where I wanted to add things that couldn't go in a preferencescreen so I made the second layout into its own activity. Looks like this now:

http://youtu.be/veGLlyPJSu8